# Android SQLite cursor returning junk

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-activity, android-cursor

My database is definitely being populated correctly (<3 SQLite Database Browser), but when I try to list all the records in a view, I get the following:

```
com.example.AppName.ObjectName@4055e8c6
com.example.AppName.ObjectName@3456e789
com.example.AppName.ObjectName@4563e5b0
```

I am using simple_list_item_1 and an ArrayAdapter.

Create statement in my activity class:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_objects);

    datasource = new ObjectsDatabase(this);
    datasource.open();

    List<Object> values = datasource.getSavedObjects();

    ArrayAdapter<ObjectName> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ObjectName>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

XML layout for above activity class:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onButton1Click"
        android:text="@string/menu_back" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you use an ArrayAdapter and not a SimpleCursorAdapter(that is designed to work with Cursors and SQLite)?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you are trying to see the value of `Object` class , which returns you a correct value as

```
com.example.AppName.ObjectName@4055e8c6
com.example.AppName.ObjectName@3456e789
com.example.AppName.ObjectName@4563e5b0
```

Try to return `String` not `Object` and create `List<String>`. You can always create your own type of `element`, get that custom class object and return the `String` value of it.

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_saved_objects);

    datasource = new ObjectsDatabase(this);
    datasource.open();

    List<String> values = datasource.getSavedObjects();

    ArrayAdapter<ObjectName> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<ObjectName>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: This makes complete sense to me, I'm just not sure where in the code this is occurring. Thank you for your answer, I will play around with this :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the default implementation of `toString()` for your `ObjectName` objects.

Override `toString()` in your `ObjectName` class to produce a string representation for display purposes.

It's also worth considering to use a cursor adapter instead of array adapter since the data apparently comes from a database query.